# mongoose - exclude embedded document from query based on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using mongoose. I have the following document in my database:

```
question: {
    "id": "60ab9bd0d40a362189e842ff",
    "deletedAt": null
        "answers": [
        {
            "id": "60ab9e4e58a72f4768c5f63b",
            "deletedAt": "2021-05-28T20:23:30.409Z",
        },
        {
            "id": "60ab9e4e58a72f4768c5f64c",
            "deletedAt": null,
        },
    }
}
```

I would like to get all questions where the `deletedAt` field is null, as well as all answers where `deletedAt` field is null.
So the result of my query should be this:

```
question: {
    "id": "60ab9bd0d40a362189e842ff",
    "deletedAt": null
        "answers": [
         {
            "id": "60ab9e4e58a72f4768c5f64c",
            "deletedAt": null,
        },
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

```
Question.aggregate([
    { $match: { deletedAt: null }},
    { $project: {
        answers: { 
          $filter: {
            input: "$answers",
            as: "answer",
            cond: { "$$answer.deletedAt": null }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { $sort: sort },
    { $limit: limit + 1 }
]}
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$eq` operator to match condition in `$filter` operator,

```
    { $project: {
        answers: { 
          $filter: {
            input: "$answers",
            as: "answer",
            cond: { 
              $eq: ["$$answer.deletedAt", null]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```